# Run GUI from another class?

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I have constructed a GUI, and now I am trying to start it from my controller (main.java) class. I have no idea how to do this. Instantiating it doesn't work (ie. GUI gui = new GUI(); doesn't work).

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing, here, but an extensive google search has yielded me no results.

I am trying to run the GUI in the main thread and have a separate thread to do calls to process code (The separate thread I have yet to make), if this has any relevance to the question. (I don't know, I'm a beginner at Java and programming!)

Comment: You might want to post some of your code so that we know what you mean by 'constructed a GUI'

Comment: This sounds like you are either missing something or your program flow is incorrect. Mind posting a little code so we can better help you?

Comment: My apologies. I will do so in the future. My problem was solved with Hovercraft's answer below, however!

Answer (score 7):

If your GUI is a Swing application, and if it extends JFrame (something I try to avoid), sometimes you also have to add

```
GUI gui = new GUI();
gui.setVisible(true);
```

But for more help, you'll need to give us more details.  Also, if you're creating Swing applications, there is a wonderful set of tutorials that you can find here: [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/index.html). These can help you create and run Swing GUI's and also and more importantly to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. It is a university project made in a group, and I didn't make the GUI, I'm just trying to patch it all together. I've bookmarked this page for now and will return to it and read the tutorials once the project rush is over. :)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I'd like to know why you're avoiding to extend JFrame. I'm also new to GUIs in Java and have to build one in an own thread.
Edit: btw, your Link to the Swing Tutorials is dead. Seems like Oracle put them in another place.